# Внешняя сортировка. Как выбрать количество сливаемых за раз файлов?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Требуется быстро отсортировать строки файла объемом в десятки ГБ.

Как выбрать количество сливаемых за раз файлов на HDD, SSD?
Как определить какой диск: SSD или HDD?
Будет-ли оптимальным на SSD слить всё за один раз?
Существует-ли алгоритм подстройки количества сливаемых файлов, взависимости от скорости чтения, числа физических дисков, дорожек (и способ получения этой информции под Виндовс на С++)?
Можно ли переложить часть работы по сливанию на котроллер диска?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под сливанием? По первому предложению у вас один файл.

Comment: Сортировка слиянием файла, не помещающегося в оперативную память. Файл сортируется по отдельным промежуткам (которые помещаются в память). Потом промежутки надо слить, что бы получить из несколькоих отсортированных промежутков один отсортрованный файл.